# URL rewriting and double slash after domain : how to make it single slash?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write a rule to redirect (301) all pages from `https://dev.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`

On the root of `dev.domain.com`, on my .htaccess I have put this single line :

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The redirection works but all subpages have a double slash.

Example : `https://dev.example.com/contact.html` is redirected to `https://www.example.com//contact.html`

Which is not working !
How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with your shown samples. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Also these Rules will look for URLs which are not having `www` in their HTTP_HOST variable part and then will remove domain name(very first part till first occurrence of `.`) with www and rest of the domain name's part.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(?:[^.]*\.)(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]
```